# Displaying in a Method

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods

**Edit: I was able to addd and display the polynomials but how do I get rid of the extra plus at the end? This is what currently displays:**

Polynomial Equation

7x^5+3x^4+10x^3+2x^2+15x^1+5x^0+1x^5=
8x^5+3x^4+10x^3+2x^2+15x^1+5x^0+

Press Enter to Exit

The plus at the very end is what I want to get rid of ^

Here is my code that I have right now. If you need clarification, just let me know!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] intCoefficients = new int[6] { 5, 15, 2, 10, 3, 7 };
        Polynomial firstpolynomial = new Polynomial(5);
        Polynomial secondpolynomial = new Polynomial(5, intCoefficients);
        Polynomial polynomialthree = new Polynomial();
        polynomialthree = firstpolynomial + secondpolynomial;

        Console.WriteLine("Polynomial Equation");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        //call the method
        secondpolynomial.Display();
        firstpolynomial.Display();
        polynomialthree.Display();

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
class Polynomial: IComparable 
{
    //fields
    int intDegree;
    int[] intCoefficient = new int[6];

    //uses IComparable
    int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)
    {
        int returnVal = -1;
        Polynomial temp = (Polynomial)o;
        if (this.Degree > temp.Degree)
        {
            returnVal = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.Degree < temp.Degree)
            {
                returnVal = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                returnVal = 0;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    //properties
    public int Degree
    {
        get
        {
            return intDegree;
        }
        set
        {
            intDegree = value;
        }
    }
    public int[] Coefficient
    {
        get
        {
            return intCoefficient;
        }
        set
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < value.Length; x++)
            {
                intCoefficient[x] = value[x];
            }
        }
    }

    //constructors
    public Polynomial() //this constructor creates the polynomial 0
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < intCoefficient.Length; x++)
        {
            intCoefficient[x] = 0;
            intDegree = 0;
        }
    }
    public Polynomial(int intDegree) //creates x^5 polynomial
    {
        this.intDegree = intDegree;
        for (int x = 0; x < intCoefficient.Length; x++)
        {
            intCoefficient[x] = 0;
        }
        intCoefficient[intDegree] = 1;
    }
    public Polynomial(int intDegree, int[] intArray) //creates other polynomial
    {
        this.intDegree = intDegree;
        for (int x = 0; x < intCoefficient.Length; x++)
        {
            intCoefficient[x] = 0;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < intArray.Length; x++)
        {
            intCoefficient[x] = intArray[x];
        }
    }
    public override string ToString() //creates polynomial equation and returns to Main()
    {

        string strPolynomial = "";

        for (int x = intDegree; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            if (intCoefficient[x] > 0 && intCoefficient[x] != 1)
            {
                strPolynomial += intCoefficient[x].ToString() + "x^" + x.ToString() + "+";
            }
            else
            {
                if (intCoefficient[x] == 1)
                {
                    strPolynomial += intCoefficient[x].ToString() + "x^" + x.ToString() + "="; 
                }
            }
        }

        return strPolynomial;
    }
    //adds first two polynomials together and returns result to the third polynomial
    public static Polynomial operator +(Polynomial firstpolynomial, Polynomial secondpolynomial)
    {
        int intAddedDegree;
        int[] intAddedCoefficient = new int[6];

        if (firstpolynomial.Degree > secondpolynomial.Degree)
        {
            intAddedDegree = firstpolynomial.Degree;
        }
        else
        {
            intAddedDegree = secondpolynomial.Degree;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < intAddedCoefficient.Length; x++)
        {
            intAddedCoefficient[x] = firstpolynomial.Coefficient[x] + secondpolynomial.Coefficient[x];
        }

        Polynomial result = new Polynomial(intAddedDegree, intAddedCoefficient);

        return result;
    }
    //display method
    public void Display() //couldn't figure out how to make the plus go away
    {
        for (int x = intDegree; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            if (intCoefficient[x] > 0 && intCoefficient[x] != 1)
            {
                Console.Write(intCoefficient[x].ToString() + "x^" + x.ToString() + "+");
            }
            else
            {
                if (intCoefficient[x] == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(intCoefficient[x].ToString() + "x^" + x.ToString() + "=");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `polynomialthree.Display()`?

Comment: You need to either override `ToString` in your `Polynomial` class to make it work the way you are doing it now or get rid of the `Console.WriteLine`s and call `firstpolynomial.Display()` (etc) instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! I just figured that out but now since I decided to display in the Display Method it messed up the order so it's not display from the highest to the lowest exponent. Instead, its display from lowest to highest. I know I have to use Array.Sort() to do that but I don't know exactly how to sort the three polynomials

Comment: I apologize for all of the updates and if there was any confusion. I have been working on this for the last few minutes and was able to make it work with one exception. When it displays the polynomials, it displays a plus at the end of the equation. How do I get rid of this?

Polynomial Equation

7x^5+3x^4+10x^3+2x^2+15x^1+5x^0+1x^5=
8x^5+3x^4+10x^3+2x^2+15x^1+5x^0+

Press Enter to Exit

Comment: By removing the part of the code that adds the plus.

Comment: If I do that, then it will not include the plus when adding the two equations. See updated code, as well as description for what I mean.

Comment: this command: `Console.Write(intCoefficient[x].ToString() + "x^" + x.ToString() + "+");` always writes a `+` in the end regardless if there are more terms to display. You have to make it smarted by adding the last `+` only when needed.

Comment: What if you call `new Polynomial(7);`? Your code will fail spectacularly. Why don't you initialize the `intCoefficient[]` array in the constructors where you know how many terms you have.

Comment: Your `Display()` method should use the output from `ToString()` so you only write the code once that converts into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Not a trivial problem, and you have *many* code quality issues. Try to understand this code which IMHO is much more flexible, streamlined and robust.

All the interesting logic is in `ToString()` which creates a string of the polynomial. The diplay function just writes the output of `ToString()` into the console window.

```
static class Program
{
    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] intCoefficients = new int[] { 5, 15, 2, 10, 3, 7 };
        Polynomial firstpolynomial = new Polynomial(5);
        Polynomial secondpolynomial = new Polynomial( intCoefficients );
        Polynomial polynomialthree;
        polynomialthree=firstpolynomial+secondpolynomial;

        Console.WriteLine("Polynomial Equation");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //call the method
        secondpolynomial.Display();
        firstpolynomial.Display();
        polynomialthree.Display();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Polynomial : IComparable, IComparable<Polynomial>
{
    readonly int[] intCoefficient;
    //constructors
    public Polynomial() //this constructor creates the polynomial 0
        : this(0) { }
    public Polynomial(int intDegree) //creates x^5 polynomial
    {
        this.intCoefficient=new int[intDegree+1];
        this.intCoefficient[intDegree]=1;
    }
    public Polynomial(params int[] intArray) //creates other polynomial
    {
        this.intCoefficient=intArray;
    }

    //properties
    public int Degree
    {
        get
        {
            return intCoefficient.Length-1;
        }
    }
    public int[] Coefficient
    {
        get
        {
            return intCoefficient;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the polynomial to a string representation
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A string object</returns>
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<=Degree; i++)
        {
            int coef = intCoefficient[i];
            int sign = Math.Sign(coef);
            coef=Math.Abs(coef);
            if (coef>0)
            {
                if (sign<0)
                {
                    // always add a leading negative when needed
                    result.Append("-");
                }
                else if (result.Length>0)
                {
                    // only add a leading plus if not first term
                    result.Append("+");
                }
                // append Cx^i terms
                if (coef>1&&i>1)
                {
                    result.AppendFormat("{0}x^{1}", coef, i);
                }
                else if (coef>1&&i==1)
                {
                    result.AppendFormat("{0}x", coef);
                }
                else if (coef>1&&i==0)
                {
                    result.AppendFormat("{0}", coef);
                }
                else if (coef==1&&i==1)
                {
                    result.Append("x");
                }
                else if (i==0)
                {
                    result.Append(coef.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    result.AppendFormat("x^{0}", i);
                }
            } // ignore term of coef==0
        }            
        return result.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the coefficients of two polynomials
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="firstpolynomial">A polynomial</param>
    /// <param name="secondpolynomial">Another polynomial</param>
    /// <returns>The resulting polynomial</returns>
    public static Polynomial operator +(Polynomial firstpolynomial, Polynomial secondpolynomial)
    {
        // Always make sure the first polynomial has equal or more terms
        if (secondpolynomial.Degree>firstpolynomial.Degree)
        {
            // Reverse the operation
            return secondpolynomial+firstpolynomial;
        }
        // Result must have same degree as first poly
        int result_degree = firstpolynomial.Degree;
        int[] result_coef = new int[result_degree+1];
        for (int i = 0; i<secondpolynomial.intCoefficient.Length; i++)
        {
            // Add coefficients from two polynomials
            result_coef[i]=firstpolynomial.intCoefficient[i]+secondpolynomial.intCoefficient[i];
        }
        for (int i = secondpolynomial.intCoefficient.Length; i<result_coef.Length; i++)
        {
            // Assign remaining coefficients from fist polynomial
            result_coef[i]=firstpolynomial.intCoefficient[i];
        }
        return new Polynomial(result_coef);
    }
    //display method
    public void Display() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ToString());
    }

    public int CompareTo(Polynomial other)
    {
        // Just compare the order of the polynmomials
        return Degree.CompareTo(other.Degree);
    }
    int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)
    {
        if (o is Polynomial)
        {
            return CompareTo(o as Polynomial);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Polynomial Equation

5+15x+2x^2+10x^3+3x^4+7x^5
x^5
5+15x+2x^2+10x^3+3x^4+8x^5


Press Enter to Exit
```

Comment: While I do see the purpose of streamlined and optimized code, this code does work aside from the extra plus. Also, I have thought about changing the 7 that someone referenced to intCoefficiants.Length - 1, which should make the code work regardless except then the array in the polynomial class would have to be changed as well. My main goal was  to get the code working and then optimize it.

Comment: a) Your code has repeating code between `ToString()` and `Display()`. b) Your code limits the polynomial order. c) Your code makes `Polynomial` is mutable type which typically leads to side effects. d) Your code initializes a instances outside of the constructor. e) Your code does not simplify the output when the exponent is 1, or when the coefficient is 0 or 1. Lastly your code uses Hungarian notation which is discouraged with `C#` (I kept it to minimize the changes from your code).